# How to check if a class in javascript exists

Tags: javascript

I am defining a class in javascript using this...

```
// file_a.js
function class_a() {
    this.prop1 = null;
    this.prop2 = null;
}

// file_b.js
var obj = new class_a;
// I need to check here if class_a exists
```

How can I do this?

Regards

Comment: Nitpicky: *Classes* don't exist in JavaScript :) (only objects (functions are also objects) and some primitive types)

Comment: Title can be improved

Answer (score 84, accepted):

```
if (typeof class_a === 'function')
```

Comment: This won't work when the class has not yet been defined.

Comment: @OlleHärstedt — If it hasn't yet been defined, then `class_a` will be `undefined` so `typeof class_a` will be the string `'undefined'`, so the `===` test will evaluate as `false` which is the correct answer. It works perfectly.

Comment: Correct, my fault. I had an error at a different place that confused me.

Comment: what if i have class name in string? typeof window['className'] === 'function' will always return false?

Comment: Be aware that this only works in simple cases when class_a is directly under window. This doesn't work for module1.class1 since module1 might be also undefined.